# Change Var to 0 after button click

Tags: javascript, html

In my javascript I have an autoscroll wich is set to var speed 1. I want to set the var spped to 0 when there is clicked on a button. Somebody out there who can help me?

Button:

```
<button name="NONAUTO"  value="">Turn off Autoscroll</button>
```

Here's my Javascript:

```
var speed=1;
var currentpos=0,alt=1,curpos1=0,curpos2=-1;

function initialize(){
    startit();
}

function scrollwindow(){
    if (document.all && !document.getElementById)
        temp=document.body.scrollTop;
    else
        temp=window.pageYOffset;

    if (alt==0)
        alt=0;
    else
        alt=0;

    if (alt==0)
        curpos1=temp;
    else
        curpos2=temp;

    if (curpos1!=curpos2){

        if (document.all)
            currentpos=document.body.scrollTop+speed;
        else
            currentpos=window.pageYOffset+speed;

        window.scroll(0,currentpos);
    } 
    else {
        currentpos=0;
        window.scroll(0,currentpos);
    }
}

function startit(){
    setInterval("scrollwindow()",50);
}

window.onload=initialize;
```

The autoscroll is interruptable, you can free scroll but if you can fix if you scroll and wait like 20 seconds and thenproceed the autoscroll that would be great!But this is just an extra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this.

```
 <button onClick = "turnOff(event)" name="NONAUTO"  value="">Turn off Autoscroll</button>
```

in the script file add this function.

```
var turnOff = function(event)
{
  event.preventDefault();
  speed = 0;
  alert(speed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an onclick attribute to the button like `onclick = change()` .

And, you can make the following `change()` function :

`function change(){
start = 0;}`

You can also add onclick event listener by `document.getElementsByName("NONAUTO")[0].addEventListener("click",change,false)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you could use:

```
<button id="buttId" name="NONAUTO"  value="">Turn off Autoscroll</button>
$( "#buttId" ).click( function()
{
  speed = 0;
}
```

or if you don't want to add an ID attribute:

```
$( "[name='NONAUTO']" ).click( function()
{
  speed = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to use `Event Handlers` in `JavaScript`. You specifically need to handle the *Click* event of the particular `button`. You can do this in the `html` code itself like other have mentioned. This is called *Obtrusive JavaScript*. **It is generally recommended to use *Unobtrusive JavaScript***. Here's one way you can do it using the Event Listeners :

```js
window.onload = function() {
var speed = 1;
  var button = document.getElementById("nonAuto");
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  speed = 0;
  alert(speed);
  });
};
```

```html
<button name="NONAUTO" id="nonAuto" value="">Turn off Autoscroll</button>
```

You can also toggle the autoscroll value in this way :

```js
window.onload = function() {
var speed = 1;
  var button = document.getElementById("nonAuto");
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
   if (speed === 1) {
      speed = 0;
       button.firstChild.data = "Turn on AutoScroll";
       alert(speed);
   }
    else {
      speed = 1;
       button.firstChild.data = "Turn off AutoScroll";
       alert(speed);
   }
  });
};
```

```html
<button name="NONAUTO" id="nonAuto" value="">Turn off Autoscroll</button>
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: This helps alot! Thank you for your time and help! But the snipper application works, but if I try it in my own code it doesnt. I have to delete the `window.onload=initialize`? what do i have to delete and what not in my code? Again thank you for your time!

Comment: @JonathanV.n. `windows.onload` should be a function. Your code should within that

Answer (score -1):

You want to change the variable speed, from 1 to 0 when a button is clicked.
Simply just write this in your html file:

```
<button onClick:'var speed = 0'></button>
```

Comment: why redeclare a var?

Comment: So in this way the variable spees is changed to 0

Comment: Or, he can declare and oblect and set one of its components to be called speed. and then use the setSpeed statement to happen on button clock

Comment: sorry, am not an expert

Comment: @OrfeoTerkuci Please at least test out the code you are claiming is an answer. This is not the place for making guesses.